# Multiple int input in same line python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, integer, valueerror

I want to take multiple integer inputs in the same line. I know I can take str input and then convert them into integer in the next line but is there any way I can do it in the same line.

I have tried this:

```
x,y = int(input("->")).split()
print(x,y)
```

I am getting this error :
 `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You messed up with parenthesis (split works on string not int)
then you expect a tuple for x,y = ...

the solution is:

```
x, y = [int(i) for i in input("->").split()]
print(x, y)
```

Comment: you can also use this solution for more variables like x, y, z, u = [the same code]

Answer (score 0):

You are taking int as input which cant be split

```
x,y = input("->").split()
print(x,y)
```

you can change to int if you like later

```
print(int(x),int(y))
```